# How do you select data label option element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="customRadio1">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="patient" id="customRadio1" autocomplete="off" > Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="customRadio2">
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="patient" id="customRadio2" autocomplete="off" > No
    </label>
    </div>
```

It is manually activated by adding the **active** class

This should work but it doesn't

```
$("input[name=patient][value='1']").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Your code works well here. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont see the result, because you havenot close tag `label` at the right place

```js
$("input[name=patient][value='1']").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="customRadio1"></label>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="patient" id="customRadio1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="customRadio2"></label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="patient" id="customRadio2" autocomplete="off"> No
</div>
```